# Wrong output of heredoc command

Tags: heredoc

Output of the code

```
echo <<<END
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
END;
```

Shoud look like that:

1st line
2nd line
3rd line

but it gives me:

1st line 2nd line 3rd line

instead... Any reason for that behavior? Obviously I can use `<br />` but heredoc should act differently right?

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the page source, it will show you that they are each on a different line but in HTML, that doesn't matter. If you want the output when viewed as HTML to have line breaks, you must use the `<br />` tag.

Comment: Well I know that HTML and in fact PHP are ignoring those but according to http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php output should be as 3 rows. Also in that book http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0672329166/helion-20 they say it should be in 3 rows so I`m confused now a little bit.

Comment: @user3050628 It does output in 3 rows. Reload your page and then `right click -> view page source`. The output is in 3 rows but HTML doesn't care about line breaks. The rule is that if you want to have a line break, use `<br />`, that's what it's for.

Comment: Yes in fact it looks like it is in source code. I just thought theres an error somewhere